# Disallowing rule in EC2 security group is not affecting already-established MongoDB connections

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

This is the case:

1. Instance `X` is able to connect to instance `Y` on TCP port `27017` (allowed by EC2 security group)
2. `X` has mongo shell
3. `Y` has MongoDB running, accepting connection from `X` on port `27017`
4. From `X`, use mongo shell to connect to DB instance on `Y`
5. From this mongo shell session on `X`, query from `Y` and insert to `Y`. All is successful.
6. Change security group of `Y`: remove the rule of port `27017` mentioned in #1
7. `X` can still query from/insert to DB hosted on `Y`. This is not expected.
8. Exit mongo shell session on `X`
9. Try step 4 again and failed. This is normal and expected.

Expectation is that EC2 network firewall will terminate connections that violate the rules (the security group policies).

Could you please explain how #7 above happens? And how can that be avoided (so `X` cannot do anything to `Y` at that time)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Expectation is that EC2 network firewall will terminate connections
>   that violate the rules

You're making an assumption here. That might be your expectation of how it should work, but where is that backed up in the official AWS documentation? I suggest reading the documentation instead of making assumptions about how this will work.

From [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html):

> An existing flow of traffic that is tracked may not be interrupted
>   when you remove the security group rule that enables that flow.
>   Instead, the flow is interrupted when it's stopped by you or the other
>   host for at least a few minutes (or up to 5 days for established TCP
>   connections). For UDP, this may require terminating actions on the
>   remote side of the flow. An untracked flow of traffic is immediately
>   interrupted if the rule that enables the flow is removed or modified.
>   For example, if you remove a rule that allows all inbound SSH traffic
>   (0.0.0.0/0) to the instance, then your existing SSH connections to the
>   instance are immediately dropped.
>
> If you want to ensure that traffic is immediately interrupted when you
>   remove a security group rule, you can use a network ACL for your
>   subnet — network ACLs are stateless and therefore do not automatically
>   allow response traffic. For more information, see Network ACLs in the
>   Amazon VPC User Guide.

Comment: Thank you, Mark, for editing tags and giving the reference! I should have dug more into AWS documentation :)